Why don't the Bene Gesserit retaliate against Vladimir Harkonnen for trying to kill Jessica and Paul?
In 2021's Dune: Part One movie, Vladimir Harkonnen promised the Bene Gesserit that the Harkonnens will not harm Jessica and Paul, and Vladimir Harkonnen is aware that the Bene Gesserit are powerful enough to find out if Harkonnens would kill them.
By movie plot, Vladimir Harkonnen says "we will not kill them but the desert will" like he will formally comply with his promise.
Isn't it obvious that the Bene Gesserit would easily find out that the Harkonnens tried to kill Jessica and Paul and they survived only thanks to their psychic abilities? Why didn't the Bene Gesserit retaliate against the Harkonnens? Is this plot element somehow described in the book?

Retaliate in what way? The most overt actions we see the BG take (as an organization) are generally arranging marriages.

The Harkonnens have advantages they do not realize, and by doing nothing the Bene Gesserits will get both revenge and what they really want.
Though the Baron does not know it, the Bene Gesserit can not immediately retaliate against his family, because the Harkonnen family contains genes that are vital to the BG's long-term plan (the Baron is Jessica's father).
Furthermore, there's no real need for revenge against the Baron, as the BG's backup for Paul is Feyd-Rautha, who is the Baron's named-heir and will probably murder the Baron very soon anyway, without the BG's needing to take open action (and thus perhaps reveal their power - remember they present themselves as servants of mankind, not as a power unto themselves), while revenge against the House Harkonnen might harm Feyd-Rautha - which would be against BG interests.

This.  It's all about the long game based in genes for the BG.  Everything is about their long term plans and they subvert everything, including themselves, to those plans.

It is also worth noting, along that same line of thought, that the BG weren't all that happy with the existence of Paul anyway. Giving birth to a male child was a violation of the BG instructions on the part of Jessica. I'm quite sure that right from the moment the Atreides were called to take hold of Arrakis, it became clear to the BG that Paul and Jessica may not survive. So yes, the BG were always careful to weigh their options in light of contingencies. In fact (possible spoiler), as it would turn out, they probably would have wished in retrospect that Paul had been done away with....

In the book Baron Harkonnen is even more circumspect than that; he won't even directly suggest that Paul and Jessica be killed:

The Baron turned with that dancing lightness the suspensors gave him. "Joke? I? Remember—I am giving up the boy. You heard what the traitor said about the lad's training. They are alike, this mother and son—deadly." The Baron smiled. "I must go now. I will send in the guard I've reserved for this moment. He's stone deaf. His orders will be to convey you on the first leg of your journey into exile. He will subdue this woman if he sees her gain control of you. He'll not permit you to untie her gag until you're off Arrakis. If you choose not to leave... he has other orders."
"You don't have to leave," Piter said. "I've chosen."
"Ah, hah!" the Baron chortled. "Such quick decision can mean only one thing."
"I will take the duchy," Piter said.
And Jessica thought: Doesn't Piter know the Baron's lying to him? But—how could he know? He's a twisted Mentat.
The Baron glanced down at Jessica. "Is it not wonderful that I know Piter so well? I wagered with my Master at Arms that this would be Piter's choice. Hah! Well, I leave now. This is much better. Ah-h, much better. You understand, Lady Jessica? I hold no rancor toward you. It's a necessity. Much better this way. Yes. And I've not actually ordered you destroyed. When it's asked of me what happened to you, I can shrug it off in all truth."
"You leave it to me then?" Piter asked.
"The guard I send you will take your orders," the Baron said. "Whatever's done I leave to you." He stared at Piter. "Yes. There will be no blood on my hands here. It's your decision. Yes. I know nothing of it. You will wait until I've gone before doing whatever you must do. Yes. Well... ah, yes. Yes. Good."
He fears the questioning of a Truthsayer, Jessica thought. Who? Ah-h-h, the Reverend Mother Gaius Helen, of course! If he knows he must face her questions, then the Emperor is in on this for sure. Ah-h-h-h, my poor Leto.
With one last glance at Jessica, the Baron turned, went out the door. She followed him with her eyes, thinking: It's as the Reverend Mother warned—too potent an adversary.

Note how Baron Harkonnen got himself out of the room before any talk of killing or stranding happened; he can truthfully testify that he didn't even hear it discussed.
The Bene Gesserit will undoubtedly know that Baron Harkonnen is almost definitely responsible for Jessica and Paul's deaths, but without any truth they can compel from him to demonstrate that he had them killed, they can't directly retaliate against him.

I think the Baron is much more concerned about the Emperor and the Landsraad finding out, not the Bene Gesserit. The Emperor may find out via his truthsayer, but the BG are not much of a threat to the Baron themselves.

@usul especially as the BG are pretty much instrumental in arranging the entire episode of sending the Atreides family to Dune to have them wiped out. The Baron wouldn't know that, and probably was under explicit instructions only to kill the Duke. The BG considered Paul an abomination and wanted to get rid of him, they were scared out of their wits by his very existence.

Didn't he expect Piter would kill them? I think it can't be truthfully said he didn't take any actions he knew likely would lead to them being killed. I don't know how specific BGs truth-telling abilities are, so maybe that's fine. But it seems a bit silly.

The missionaria protectiva had already prepared the way in the desert by laying the Kwisatz Haderach myth down among the Fremen.
From Dune, just before the old Reverend Mother, Gaius Helen Mohiam  tests the boy Paul:

Jessica turned away, looked out the window at the gathering darkness.
"Is it really that terrible, this planet of Arrakis?"  "Bad enough,
but not all bad. The Missionaria Protectiva has been in there and
softened it up somewhat." The Reverend Mother heaved herself to her
feet, straightened a fold in her gown.

Paul was already trained in the BG ways:

"I observed you in pain, lad. Pain's merely the axis of the test. Your
mother's told you about our ways of observing. I see the signs of her
teaching in you. Our test is crisis and observation."

Jessica was advised by her that Paul needed more training and fast:

"Now, I caution you," said the old woman, "to ignore the regular order
of training. His own safety requires the Voice. He already has a good
start in it, but we both know how much more he needs . . . and that
desperately." She stepped close to Paul, stared down at him. "Goodbye,
young human. I hope you make it. But if you don't -- well, we shall
yet succeed."

Paul and Jessica had been well trained and were expected to survive. But if they didn't, then the Bene Gesserit's plan would adapt and still go ahead.
The Baron was certain that at some point he would be questioned by  the Bene Gesserit, Gaius Helen Mohiam:

"She was my teacher at the Bene Gesserit school. Now, she's the
Emperor's Truthsayer. [...]"

...so he (the Baron) made provision for this in his actions:

"I must go now. I will send in the guard I've reserved for this
moment. He's stone deaf. His orders will be to convey you on the first
leg of your journey into exile. [...]"

All the BG and the Emperor would know when the Baron is questioned would be that they were sent into exile in the desert.
The BG would have no proof of murder on the part of the Baron, besides, they had contingency plans (Feyd-Rautha).
If Paul survives, the plot to kill him, the Baron, and the Emperor himself will no longer matter. The plan will have succeeded and the BG will have a male BG in a position of power - for them to control (so they think).

Paul was trained by Jessica despite explicit orders by the Reverent Mother not to do so. This AFTER her giving birth to Paul despite explicit orders to only bear daughters (who could then be married off to Feyd-Rautha Harkonen, uniting the lines). Because of those acts by Jessica, Paul had to be eliminated (and the Harkonens indeed tried to do just that). The MP planted myth had nothing to do with Paul, and caused the imperial (BG actually) plan to massively backfire.

The framing of the question is mismatched to the nature of the Bene Gesserit. It isn't like a Great House. It's more like an exclusive university or a secret society. So, several reasons:

An attack on one member is not viewed as an attack on the organization. Bene Gesserit are in political positions throughout the universe -- in fact, since so many powerful women are BG, they are probably on opposite sides of wars against each other all the time. This kind of incident -- one Great House attacking another and killing a BG -- is probably pretty common.
The BG's goal is to influence and shepherd humanity as a whole over a long, long time horizon, by placing members in positions of power. Individual members are like ants, expendable in service of the goal. (Bloodlines and genes are more important, as other answers discuss.) Jessica's job was to perpetuate some genes and influence some politics. Getting killed in a house war is an expected risk.
The BG does not appear to have a strong formal structure in a military sense. They give breeding directions to their members, but there is no precedent for the organization to come to a decision to e.g. declare war, deploy some attack plan, and expect the rest of the organization to follow orders and attack people.
Retaliation doesn't necessarily serve the goals of the BG (as other answers discuss). More broadly, the BG doesn't want to become a political or war-waging organization. If they get in the habit of fighting, or even sabotaging, then there will be alliances and oppositions and the BG will no longer be welcome in many Houses. They want to be tolerated and useful everywhere. Similarly, they don't want to reveal more powers or be feared and distrusted any more than they already are.

Further reading:

What was the source of power/influence which the Bene Gesserit had?
What is the endgame of the Bene Gesserit?

